# Почему не стартует процесс extract oracle golden gate?

Tags: oracle, goldengate

В наличии Windows 2008 R2 сервер. Oracle 10, Oracle golden gate 12.
Создал процес экстракта. При запуске в логи менеджера пишет, что процесс запустился.
Однако процесс сразу останавливается, но логов по этому делу не пишет. Во всяком случае в подкаталоге dirrpt отсуствуют файлы логов, кроме лога менеджера.
Файл параметров был взян с рабочей реплики под OGG11. Данные для подключения к БД и сохранения трейл файлов были изменены на корректные.

В чем может быть проблема? Куда копать?

PS
  После установки ОГГ при старте ругался на отсуствие MSVCR100.DLL. Скачал нужную дллку из интернета. Разрядность библиотеки совпадает с разрядностью сервера и разрядностью голден гейта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что не хватает нужных dll.
При старте процессов через менеджер ошибки не появляются. Если стартовать процессы самому через командную строку, то ошибки начинают отображаться.
Не хватало оракловых библиотек из 11 версии, которой у меня не было установлено и некоторых майкрософтовских. Собственно скачал их, и проблема решилась